# Is there a way to make a webpage go back and then forward again in the history using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube, adblock

I need to find a way to make a webpage go back then forward in the history as I am creating a simple YouTube adblocker chrome extension. So far, I have:

```js
history.back();
history.forward();
```

However, this just goes back to the previous webpage.
Is there any way to possibly implement this?

Comment: If the extension has the permission, it can keep track of all pages the user loads or clicks that updates the browser. You do not need to use the history api's back and forward

Comment: This is the way. If you are going back more then expected it probably means its an SPA. In this case, going back in the history has no use as there is no page refresh on the site.

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as "a simple Youtube adblocker".

Comment: back+forward doesn't seem to serve any purpose. What do you want to achieve through that? Maybe there's a different solution.